# How can I get nicely formatted and syntax highlighted details for Dart/Flutter suggestions in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

In VS Code the "Quick Documentation" looks like:
[image]

the arguments are uncomfortable to read.

Is there any way to make the arguments look like below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not supported at the time of this writing, but there's an open issue ticket asking for it: [Code completion descriptions are not syntax-coloured #2792](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2792). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

Currently, the Dart VS Code extension puts the signature in the `detail` field, which doesn't support syntax highlighting, so either it needs to move it to the `documentation` field ([source](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2792#issuecomment-716666911)) or it needs to wait for the `detail` field to support it ([source](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2792#issuecomment-723900924)).